# How far is Louros from Ioannina (Greece)?

Tags: greece

I'll visit family next month in Ioannina, Greece. I'll stay there for couple of weeks. However I have a friend who lives in Louros which I think is not that far away. Can anyone tell me how far away that is and how I can best get there?

Comment: To check how far away it is use Google Maps. We can help you how to get there, but then you have to define what best means to you: is it the fastest, the cheapest, etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about distance that can be looked up on Google Maps, not a travel question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is approx. 80km away.

The best way to get there is either by car, which would be about 1h drive or with the local buses (called KTEL).

There are several busses daily going from Ioannina to Preveza and back.

For route planning visit http://www.ktelioannina.gr

The bus is actually starting from Ioannina and the final destination is Preveza. Louros is on the route, 25km before reaching Preveza. So when booking your ticket state that you are going to Louros.

Hope this helps